# Where do I find the Xilinx xc7z007sclg400-1 master constaint file?

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I am trying to find the Master Xilinx design constraint file for the xc7z007sclg400-1.

Does anyone know where I can find that?

Comment: For which FPGA board do you want the constraint file? Constraint file is based on board design that FPGA is placed on. There is no constraint file just for the FPGA chip.